# How to sort values in a two dimensional array suitable to the other values?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, bluej

```
public class Spieler
{
    public Magier Henri = new Magier ("Magier Henri");    
    public Krieger Christian = new Krieger ("Krieger Christian");   
    public Supporter Judith = new Supporter ("Suppporter Judith");
    public Schuetze Lukas = new Schuetze ("Schuetze Lukas");
    public Magier Nick = new Magier ("Magier Nick");    
    public Krieger Anna = new Krieger ("Krieger Anna");   
    public Supporter Neele = new Supporter ("Suppporter Neele");
    public Schuetze Christoph = new Schuetze ("Schuetze Christoph");   
    public int i;
    public int besten5;
    public int bestPlayerEU;
    public int[][] kandidat = new int[8][2]; 
    int t;

    public void fuelleArray()
    {
        kandidat[0][0] = Henri.getGesamtPunkte();
        kandidat[0][1] = 1;
        kandidat[1][0] = Christian.getGesamtPunkte();
        kandidat[1][1] = 2;
        kandidat[2][0] = Judith.getGesamtPunkte();
        kandidat[2][1] = 3;
        kandidat[3][0] = Lukas.getGesamtPunkte();
        kandidat[3][1] = 4;
        kandidat[4][0] = Nick.getGesamtPunkte();
        kandidat[4][1] = 5;
        kandidat[5][0] = Anna.getGesamtPunkte();
        kandidat[5][1] = 6;
        kandidat[6][0] = Neele.getGesamtPunkte();
        kandidat[6][1] = 7;
        kandidat[7][0] = Christoph.getGesamtPunkte();
        kandidat[7][1] = 8;
    }

    public int[][] sort()
    {
        fuelleArray();
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < kandidat.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j < kandidat.length-i; j++)
            {
                if(kandidat[j][t] < kandidat[j-1][t])
                {
                    temp = kandidat [j-1][t];
                    kandidat[j-1][t] = kandidat [j][t];
                    kandidat[j][t] = temp;
                }
            }
        } 
        return kandidat;
    }
}
```

So here I get the left side of my Array with random values sorted but I also want that the values on the right side of the two dimensional array move suitable to the characters. So I want that the `kandidat` "Henri" is still the value `1`, "Christian" = `2`, "Judith" = `3`, "Lukas" = `4` and so on. Can someone explain or write code so the numbers on the right side of the array move suitable to the characters / `kandidat`s?

So when the array looks like this in the beginning:

```
    0    1 
0   26   1
1   45   2
2   37   3
3   33   4
4   27   5
5   29   6
6   41   7
7   49   8
```

It should look like this in the end:

```
     0    1 
0   26    1
1   27    5
2   29    6
3   33    4
4   37    3
5   41    7
6   45    2
7   49    8
```

Comment: Try explaining in detail what you want your result to be and which individual steps you need to do in order to get there.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen So the left side of the array is filled with random values and with the sort method they get sorted so the highest value is on the bottom from the array. Now in the right site of the array there are 1, 2, 3s and so on. This specific numbers belong to the each of the random values like christian should always be the number 2 or henri should always be number 1. SO the values get sorted but after the sort method i would like to identify which charakter has the highest value? how can i sort the random values and the specific numbers stay at their random values? :) pls help

Comment: Some unrelated advice: if possible, try getting into the habit of coding in English. Good practice, industry standard and also comes in handy when you end up asking questions on international platforms just like this. :)

Comment: @domdom yeah i know when i code privatly i code in english but this is a project for school and we have to name our methods and classes like the teacher does and he codes in german :/

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  i edited the post so you can see how the array should be sorted in the end :) can you understand it now? :)

Comment: I'd like to have a word with your teacher... anyway, here goes another unrelated advice: in Java, variable/member names should be lower-case to not confuse them with class names. Hence, `public Magier Henri` should be `public Magier henri` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you want to swap the pairs of a "kandidate"+number keeping those pairs together. Have you tried something like this:

```
int[] temp = kandidat [j-1];
kandidat[j-1] = kandidat [j];
kandidat[j] = temp;
```

this swaps the pair `(kanditate[j][0], kandidate[j][1])` with the pair `(kanditate[j-1][0], kandidate[j-1][1])`.

Comment: yeah you're great! thank you very much! i also had to remove the definition of int temp = 0; now it works. nice :)

Comment: You're welcome. Funny how you marked this as correct but not upvote it as useful though :p

Comment: the upvote gets recorded but my reputations are under 15 so it Doesn't show up :D

Comment: Ah right! Thx :) Completely forgot about that, so it looked weird.